# GeoRedirect using the free API

Tags: javascript, redirect, geoip, maxmind

I've been trying to use the free database from Maxmind to geo-redirect my companies website. For some reason the code was working before, but it won't work no - and the link to it either shows unauthorised or unavailable.

Can someone shed some light on this?

The links available are...

```
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/country.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But this seems to link to no-where.

A snippet of code used is below.

```
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/app/country.js" charset="ISO-8859-1" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">loc = (geoip_country_code());if (loc == 'US') {window.location = "http://usa.example.com/";}if (loc == 'GB') {window.location = "http://uk.example.com/";}
```

Any ideas what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

The Maxmind Javascript is no more free.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for free (first 100,000 requests each day) or affordable GeoIP service, you could use [Cloudflare Workers](https://workers.cloudflare.com) which offers [location metadata for every request](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/request/#incomingrequestcfproperties), you just need to write simple function to send it to your frontend.

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  const cf = event.request.cf;
  const data = {
    colo: .cf.colo,
    country: .cf.country,
    city: .cf.city,
    continent: .cf.continent,
    latitude: .cf.latitude,
    longitude: .cf.longitude,
    postalCode: .cf.postalCode,
    metroCode: .cf.metroCode,
    region: .cf.region,
    regionCode: .cf.regionCode,
    timezone: .cf.timezone
  }
  const json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

  return event.respondWith(
    new Response(json, {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      },
    })
  );
});
```